# Find the values that $(x-y)(x+y)$ can take.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$-3 \le x \lt 2 $$

$$1 \lt y \lt 3 $$

Find the values that $(x-y)(x+y)$ can take.

I know that $(x-y)(x+y)$ is given by

$$x^2-y^2$$

So, we have to square the both inequality but I couldn't do it.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$$-3 \le x \lt 2 \implies 0 \le x^2 \le 9 $$

$$1 \lt y \lt 3 \implies 1 \lt y^2 \lt 9\implies -9 \lt -y^2 \lt -1$$

thus: $$-9 < x^2-y^2 < 8$$

[image]

Comment: Does it have any rule? If both sides negative or positive, we square the both, right?

Comment: The better way to see it is consider the graph $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @woofy of course, thanks!

Comment: @Flisch I've added a picture to explain better how it works

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* What is the largest possible value of $x^2$ and what is the least possible value of $y^2$ in the intervals given?

Answer (score 0):

$$0\le x^2 < 9$$
$$1 < y^2 < 9$$
$$-9 < x^2-y^2 < 8$$

Comment: we get $$-9<x^2-y^2<8$$

Comment: Does it have any rule? If both sides negative or positive, we square the both, right?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ in the first two lines should be $x^2$ and $y^2$, and also $x^2\leq 9$

Comment: @woofy thx. fixed.